# TeamCity set a default value for select parameter

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a configuration where one of the parameters is a "Select" parameter with allow multiple selection.
The following screen shots describe it:

[image]

I want this test to be triggered automatically where this Select parameter will select label "a" and "c".
Is there any way to add a default value to this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the values of variable using separator ( ; ) like below image
In this case by default A and C are selected.

[image]